# Hibernate L2C hits is taking a long time 25k hits-> 1.7 seconds

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, caching

I have a spring boot 2.1.8 application where most objects are cached in L2 cache of hibernate. Collections are cached as well (eagerly). I am facing a performance issue when executing a find all query. The stats are as below:

```
Session Metrics {
34225 nanoseconds spent acquiring 1 JDBC connections;
0 nanoseconds spent releasing 0 JDBC connections;
57054 nanoseconds spent preparing 1 JDBC statements;
5537918 nanoseconds spent executing 1 JDBC statements;
0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC batches;
366086602 nanoseconds spent performing 3794 L2C puts;
1732885874 nanoseconds spent performing 24779 L2C hits;
0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C misses;
72295530 nanoseconds spent executing 1 flushes (flushing a total of 20654 entities and 7817 collections);
0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 partial-flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections)
}
```

- 25K hits on L2C is taking around 1.7 sec
- each find All is reaching DB for select all query (i guess this is how the cache works, fetch the ids from DB and retrieve the objects from cache)
- Miscellaneous time being spent on puts and flushes of cache.

I am using Hibernate 5.3.11, ehCache 3.6.3

The cache hits seems to be the bottleneck. Any ideas on the root cause or any suggestions that can help improve the performance?

Comment: One cause might be the serialization overhead to store the cache values via JCache in EHCache. If you need only local caching you can try https://cache2k.org. Its faster than EHCache and it has additional optimizations switches to reduce overhead (e.g. copyAlwaysIfRequested=false). However, it makes sense to always profile before doing wild tinkering.

Comment: 1,7 seconds for 25K hits is actually not too bad. Is it possible to put a stripped down application for testing in GitHub? Then I can do some profiling and provide you some tuning changes.